# returning value from async task in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have been trying to code an app but I am stuck with a problem. I have a function checkexistence which checks weather column with column name as the current month is present or not and another function that inserts rows in the sql database but I am not able to figure out how can use both of them to check that weather current month is present or not and if not add the current month

Here is the class with the code.

```
public class Repository {
    private MonthDetailsDAO monthDetailsDAO;
    private static Repository instance;
    private YearDetailsDAO yearDetailsDAO;
    private LiveData<List<MonthDetailsEntity>> liveMonthData;
    private LiveData<List<YearDetailsEntity>> liveYearData;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Database>>Repository";

    public Repository(Application application){
        Database database = Database.getInstance(application);
        yearDetailsDAO = database.yearDetailsDAO();
        liveYearData = yearDetailsDAO.getdata();
    }


    public void add_year(YearDetailsEntity yearDetailsEntity){
        new InsertAsyncTask(yearDetailsDAO).execute(yearDetailsEntity);

    }

    public void checkExistance(YearDetailsEntity yearDetailsEntity){
          new CheckExistanceAsyncTask(yearDetailsDAO).equals(yearDetailsEntity);
    }
    public LiveData<List<YearDetailsEntity>> getLiveYearData(){
        return liveYearData;
    }





    private static class CheckExistanceAsyncTask extends  AsyncTask<YearDetailsEntity , Void , Void>{
        private YearDetailsDAO yearDetailsDAO;
        public CheckExistanceAsyncTask(YearDetailsDAO yearDetailsDAO){
            this.yearDetailsDAO = yearDetailsDAO;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(YearDetailsEntity... yearDetailsEntities) {

            int m = yearDetailsEntities[0].getMonth();
            int y = yearDetailsEntities[0].getYear();
            YearDetailsEntity yearDetailsEntity1 = yearDetailsDAO.checkExistance(m , y);
            if(yearDetailsEntity1 == null) {
//insert now

            }
            else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG , "Month already present");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<YearDetailsEntity, Void, Void> {
        private YearDetailsDAO yearDetailsDAO;
        public InsertAsyncTask(YearDetailsDAO yearDetailsDAO){
            this.yearDetailsDAO = yearDetailsDAO;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(YearDetailsEntity... yearDetailsEntities) {
            yearDetailsDAO.add_year(yearDetailsEntities[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have two asynctasks. That you have two functions is irrelevant. You want to do something with the results of two asynctasks. Please edit your post to make it readable.